# Split one attribute in XML file into two attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I'm new to XML/XSLT.

I need to transform an xml file containing elements like this:

```
<person name="John Smith" />
<person name="Mary Ann Smith" />
```

Into something like this:

```
<person firstname="John" lastname="Smith" />
<person firstname="Mary Ann" lastname="Smith" />
```

*name* attribute can contain a variable number of words, only the last one should go to *lastname* and the rest goes to *firstname*.

I'm trying to achieve this using XSLT and xsltproc on linux, but any other simple solution is welcome.

Thanks,
Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 (and thus XPath 1.0) is somewhat limited in its string manipulation functions.  There are the `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions which allows you to extract the substring of a given string preceding and following the *first* occurrence of a particular pattern, but there's no direct way to split a string at the *last* occurrence.  You'll have to use a (tail-)recursive template

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person/@name">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitName"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="splitName">
    <!-- start with nothing in $first and all the words in $rest -->
    <xsl:param name="first" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="rest" select="." />

    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if rest contains more than one word -->
      <xsl:when test="substring-after($rest, ' ')">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitName">
          <!-- move the first word of $rest to the end of $first and recurse.
               For the very first word this will add a stray leading space
               to $first, which we will clean up later. -->
          <xsl:with-param name="first" select="concat($first, ' ',
                                               substring-before($rest, ' '))" />
          <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest, ' ')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- $rest is now just the last word of the original name, and $first
             contains all the others plus a leading space that we have to
             remove -->
        <xsl:attribute name="firstname">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring($first, 2)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="lastname">
          <xsl:value-of select="$rest" />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example:

```
$ cat names.xml
<people>
  <person name="John Smith" />
  <person name="Mary Ann Smith" />
</people>
$ xsltproc split-names.xsl names.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people>
  <person firstname="John" lastname="Smith"/>
  <person firstname="Mary Ann" lastname="Smith"/>
</people>
```

If you don't want the `<?xml...?>` line then add

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

to the top of the stylesheet, immediately following the opening `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag.